# Characteristic room-temperature photon energy - is this nomogram wrong?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

Reading this recent [ars technica](http://arstechnica.com/science/2016/03/meet-the-largest-science-project-in-us-government-history-the-james-webb-telescope/) article on the James Webb telescope, something kept bothering me about the nomogram - shown below. The credit says it is from *The Opensource Handbook of Nanoscience and Nanotechnology*.

Is the graphic wrong, or am I missing something? I'm comfortable in rooms where kT is about 1/40 eV - this plot looks like it comes from Pluto!

**Question:** Approximately where on that graphic *should* the red *room temperature* line actually fall?

[image: bad nomogram]

Comment: Er ... 1/40 eV is the number I recall as well. That looks like 1/400 eV which could just be a typo on someones part.

Comment: @dmckee If the line is drawn in the wrong place, should it be called a *mouseo*, *clicko* or *drago* rather than a typo? Since it was missed by the author and the editorial staff, can we call it an *edito* or *proofo* too? :)

Comment: The spectral peak at 300K is at $9.6\mu m$. Is that what they are trying to show? That's not right, either, is it?

Comment: The scales are lined up to each other correctly, 1eV and 1μm appear roughly  in line as they should @CuriousOne. There are no ticks so it's ballpark figures. My question is only about the placement of the red line labeled "*room temperature*". That room appears to be very very cold.

Comment: Yes, the red line is in the wrong place.  It's a factor of 10 too cold.

Comment: Thanks @honeste_vivere - if you want to leave that as an answer, I can accept it and close the question - I was fairly sure that was what was wrong, but there's to better place than SE to find out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Conversion from K to eV**

Let's assume [room temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_temperature) is at ~300 K, just to make the numbers easy.  To convert to [electron volts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt), one simply does:
$$
T \ [K] \times \left( \frac{ 1.38064852 \times 10^{-23} \ J }{ 1 \ K } \right) \times \left( \frac{ 1 \ eV }{ 1.6021766208 \times 10^{-19} \ J } \right) = \left( k_{B} T \right) \ [eV] \\
\left( k_{B} T \right) \ [eV] \sim \left( \frac{ 8.61733 \times 10^{-5} eV }{ 1 \ K } \right) \times T \ [K]
$$
where $k_{B} = 1.3806505 \times 10^{-23}$ J/K is the [Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant), and $1.6021766208 \times 10^{-19}$ J/eV is an energy conversion factor equivalent in magnitude to the [fundamental charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge).  The values shown above are the [2014 CODATA/NIST](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Constants/index.html) values.

> **Question:** Approximately where on that graphic should the red room temperature line actually fall?

## **Answer**

So using the above we find that 300 K ~ 0.02585 eV or $\sim 3 \times 10^{-2}$ eV.  Therefore, the red line should be between the $10^{-1}$ and $10^{-2}$ tick marks on the eV scale bar, not the $10^{-2}$ and $10^{-3}$.

Comment: Sure that's fine if you wish.  The Boltzmann constant never changes and in kinetic theory, temperature is directly related to the average kinetic energy of a system in the bulk flow rest frame.  So it is often treated as a form of energy, though a thermodynamically-strict individual would probably object to such a casual treatment.

Comment: Sure thing, done...

Comment: Thanks for your help! I appreciate you taking the time to give a rigorous answer. It's good to have everything together in one place.